# How can i remove the expand arrow in kendo ui treeview if there are no child's to display

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using kendo ui treeview. I am loading the treeview dynamically from the database. But my issue is i am getting the expand error if there are no child's to display. How can i remove the expand arrow.

Regards,

Sri

Comment: Not having `items` in the parent.

Comment: yes. when i am not having child items to the parent also i am getting the expand arrow

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code (how you initialize the tree and the datasource)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a configuration field of the HierarchicalDataSource schema.model object called **[hasChildren](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/hierarchicaldatasource#schemamodelhaschildren%20boolean%20%20string%20%20function%20default)** you can add a boolean property to your model which indicates if the your model has items.

This way when the TreeView creates its elements it will check that property (or call the function - you could for example return if the items.leght is greater than zero) and if the returned value is false it wont create the expand arrow in front of the item.

Check [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/odata-binding.html) demo.

Answer (score 1):

for an example, I have declared my function like this in my Kendo Ui TreeView :

```
 var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        data: @Html.Raw(dataSource),
        schema: {
            model: {
                children: "Children",
                hasChildren: function(e) {
                    var test = e.Children.length;
                    return test > 0; 
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

And for my, it works perfectly !

Comment: I think it would be ideal if you showed more code or a jsfiddle.   For me it does indeed show the arrows only when it has children, but as soon as I click on a parent node arrow that I know has children i get an error :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined      `for me i have    children: "items" and then i use  e.items.length     I'm wondering if that is a reserved keyword

Comment: @Tom Stikel With kendo UI, the terms 'items' its a keywords, try with an other name of property