# Kendo UI treeview remove the expand arrow in kendo ui treeview if there are no child's to display - not working properly

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I was attempting to use this code

[How can i remove the expand arrow in kendo ui treeview if there are no child's to display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564797/how-can-i-remove-the-expand-arrow-in-kendo-ui-treeview-if-there-are-no-childs-t)

Now, it is not the selected answer, but it is partially working for me

Here is the answer I based my hasChildren on

```
var inline = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: @Html.Raw(dataSource),
    schema: {
        model: {
            children: "Children",
            hasChildren: function(e) {
                var test = e.Children.length;
                return test > 0; 
            }
        }
    }
});
```

My code looks like this:

```
children: "items",
//hasChildren: "Id"  // Id I was using as that is a key 
hasChildren: function(e) {
    var test = e.items.length;
    return test > 0; 
}
```

1. The load of the data looks great.  All collapsed and I see that ONLY the parent nodes WITH children have Arrow icons .  Perfect
2. Problem, as soon as I click to expand any Parent Node I get an **error**

   ```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
   ```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the **items** property is sometimes null. Give a try to check if it exists first.

```
return e.items && e.items.length;
```

Comment: I will try that, thanks.    I seem to have a lot of problems with Kendo, I do see that there are several people on stackoverflow that seem to know kendo quite well,  however since it is a commercial product , is it using best to post questions to Telerik/Kendo forums ?    Anyways  I have a problem that many you can look at this question of mine if you get a chance,  thx in advance      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228952/kendo-treeview-datasource-not-showing-children-items-in-javascript-debug-unless

Comment: I had a same problem with expand arrow but your answer helped.