# kendo treeview datasource not showing children items in javascript debug unless node is expanded

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, treeview, kendo-treeview

I have a **Kendo TreeView** in which the parent nodes and children are all gotten at the same time.

Previously I was having the separate calls of which unless a Parent node was expanded, it did not call a query and pull that data into the parent node as children

Now that I have my data pulled all at once,  I want to be able to do all sorts of CRUD operation in which if a node is created, deleted, sort order changed, then on Button click I want to send in all the data.

**PROBLEM**:

I noticed that in doing a console.log(mydatasource.data());  **that I am seeing EMPTY children items.**

Seems that **if I expand**  ( **or expand and collapse**)  **THEN** I get the **children items to show up in chrome dev tools output**

This is certainly a huge problem as I'm trying to send in the complete **data** and then run CRUD operations on all the data from essentially 3 database tables....

**Why and how is this happening?**

```
// show my data in chrome browser that is getting sent to mvc method
console.log(homogeneous.data());
```

Kendo TreeView

```
var homogeneous = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: serviceRoot + "/GetReportGroupAssignments", 
                dataType: "json" 
            }
        },

        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id" 
                ,
                children: "items",
                hasChildren: "Id"
            }
        }
    });

var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            expanded: true,
            dragAndDrop: true,
            select: onSelect,
            dataSource: homogeneous,
            dataTextField: "ReportGroupName" 
            ,
            template: kendo.template($("#treeview-template").html()) //,
        }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set **[loadOnDemand](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#configuration-loadOnDemand)** to false.

Comment: Nice,  I was about to do a "hack" to an expand and collapse with javascript,    Thx!